# Knockout.js - Utils - latest build missing makeArray function

Tags: knockout.js

Strange behavour in the [latest knockout.js build](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/build/output/knockout-latest.js)

The ko.utils debug version has the makeArray function defined. 
but it missing in the minimised version (or is it now renamed to some xx jiberish?)

Comment: As i'm using script sharp, i found the util very handy to strip a IReadonlyCollection to an array etc.  Thankfully jQuery comes with an identical function called makeArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a subset of the most useful functions are exposed in the minified build.  In the debug build, look for the ko.exportSymbol calls to see which functions are included.

So, this is intentional.  You can log an issue on github to ask for it to be exposed or take a copy of the function locally (since it is a fairly simple function and unlikely to change).